# Passing data into element from composer (based on Tweestation)

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I am building an app based on the **Tweetstation** by *miguel de icaza*. C# Monotouch. Basically, this is what I'm dealing with:

I have one view (yourAdd) with a styledstringelement (using Monotouch.Dialog) called Title. Default value is "".
I have a text composer (straight off the composer from **Tweetstation**) where the user can write a question and attach a photo.

What I want to accomplish it that when the user clicks Add in the composer, the value of the styledstringelement should change and reflect the input in the composer.

**My problem:** when the user has selected a photo (and might have some text also), he or she clicks Add. That triggers a series of events where the pic is uploaded to yFrog and we get an url back. And at the end of that, the view is dismissed and the user is again in the yourAdd view. So, the click on the button triggers the event, and we have to wait until the end to get what I want: the URL to the submitted picture (together with the text). And then I want to update the stringelement with this new info.

So, **my question**: how can I pass data from the composer class, once the callback from yFrog is done, to the stringelement?